# Why isn't Mozilla SeaMonkey available in the repositories? How can I install it?

Tags: software-installation, release-management, seamonkey

I wanted to install SeaMonkey on Ubuntu 13.04, but was surprised to see that it was nowhere to be found.

Am I missing something? How can I install it?

Comment: It's been gone quite a while :(

Comment: You  can get seamonkey in a ppa http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/ubuntuzilla?dist=all

Answer (score 7):

SeaMonkey was removed of the repositories, seen in [the publishing history](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seamonkey/+publishinghistory), for the following reason:

> requested by micahg; unsupportable for five years without dedicated maintenance, contact #ubuntu-mozillateam to help; LP: [#987713](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seamonkey/+bug/987713)

This means, that since Ubuntu can't offer support for 5 years to the package they decided to remove it. Looking at the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seamonkey/+bug/987713) we see more details:

> Since we have no one stepping up at the moment to maintain this for 5 years, I think it makes the most sense to remove it from precise. We can always backport from later releases if someone volunteers to help with this.
>
> For volunteers, please join #ubuntu-mozillateam on irc.ubuntu.com to discuss.

[They offer a way to still installing the package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seamonkey/+bug/987713/comments/2), but in this case there's no support from Ubuntu:

> SeaMonkey package is available in Ubuntuzilla depot (**tested successfully on Ubuntu 13.04**):
>
> ### To install, type the following commands:
>
> ```
> echo -e "\ndeb http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt all main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list > /dev/null
> sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com C1289A29
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install seamonkey-mozilla-build
> ```
>
> ---
>
> More info: [SourceForge.net: ubuntuzilla](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ubuntuzilla/)
>
> Alternatively, you may use Joe Lesko's PPA ( [Seamonkey Development](https://launchpad.net/~joe-nationnet/+archive/seamonkey-dev) )but it doesn't support Raring Ringtail yet.
>
> I really hope that someone will step up to maintain this high profile software. I wish I had the time to do it... :-/

If you really wants this package again in the main repositories, you should join and see what you can do to help.

Comment: Would someone like me to take this project? I may or may not be too lazy to do it. =]

Comment: @pacificfils the links are there for all. Or just drop in the irc channel

Comment: The problem with this is, if you do it you also get Firefox from that PPA, as far as I can see.

Comment: @ReinierPost is mozilla's PPA.

Answer (score 0):

It was probably removed from the Ubuntu default PPAs.

To get it back, open a terminal and type

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:joe-nationnet/seamonkey-dev
```

Type your password, there will be no characters.

When (if) prompted, hit ENTER.

When that's done,

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

After THAT is done,

```
 sudo apt-get install seamonkey-dev
```

And you'll have SeaMonkey installed. Look for it in your Dash.

**DISCLAIMER:**

While this PPA is a trusted one, some PPAs have dangerous malware disguised as benign packages. I have tested this PPA and it has resulted "safe". You can see the PPA details here: [launchpad.net/seamonkey-dev](https://launchpad.net/~joe-nationnet/+archive/seamonkey-dev)

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to install it, as the package was not found. But I did run across Ubuntuzilla (http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ubuntuzilla/index.php?title=Main_Page), and that worked.

Comment: Well, I'm glad it worked out in the end.

Comment: @guntbert There you go.