# gpg: keyserver receive failed: Connection timed out

Tags: seamonkey

I am trying to install Seamonkey.

I am using the method shown here.

[Why isn't Mozilla SeaMonkey available in the repositories? How can I install it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397272/why-isnt-mozilla-seamonkey-available-in-the-repositories-how-can-i-install-it)

When I try to do the key command, my connection times out.

```
andy@7:~$ sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com C1289A29
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.mMHsuyF3KI/gpg.1.sh --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com C1289A29
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Connection timed out
```

2/20/19 I just found out that

```
The repository 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt all Release' is not signed.
```

How can I get it signed?

Answer (score 15):

It looks like firewall blocking port `11371` which is used by gpg. Force it to use port 80 to get gpg key.

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 C1289A29
```

Alternate Command

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C1289A29
```

Comment: This won't fix the first problem, that the keyserver receive timed out.

Comment: I tried it.                                                                                                                gpg: keyserver receive failed: Connection timed out

Comment: @ Thomas Ward So how do I fix keyserver timing out?

Comment: @fixit7 edited answer.

Comment: @Ketan Patel It added the gpg key. After sudo apt-get update, I did sudo apt-get install seamonkey-mozilla-build and got E: Unable to locate package seamonkey-mozilla-build

Comment: The first command worked for me!  Thanks!

Comment: the first command also worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I got Seamonkey installed. :-)

I found the debian package here.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntuzilla/files/mozilla/apt/pool/main/s/seamonkey-mozilla-build/ 1

Not sure it will check for updates.